# StackOverflowException in MVC Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I'm running into a StackOverflowException on my MVC Partial View. We are also using Entity Framework and dependency injection through Unity.

It only happens when I have an action in my Kendo Tabstrip, like so:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("mainNav")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "mainnav" })
    .Animation(false)
    .Items(i =>
    {
        i.Add().Text("Home").Action("Dashboard", "Home");
        i.Add().Text("Clients").Action("Manage", "Household");
        i.Add().Text("Properties").Action("Manage", "Property");
        i.Add().Text("Financial").Action("FinancialSummary", "Financial");
        i.Add().Text("Payables").Action("Manage", "PurchaseOrder")
            .Content(Html.Partial("~/Views/PurchaseOrder/_ManageContent.cshtml").ToString());
        i.Add().Text("Maintenance").Action("Manage", "WorkOrder");
        i.Add().Text("Capital Planning").Action("Index", "CapitalPlanning");
    })
)
```

If I have just plain actions, like `i.Add().Text("Home")`, it works just fine.

The exception didn't want to show me the call stack (*"Unable to evaluate the expression because the thread is in a stack overflow state"*), but I did eventually think to look on the call stack tab in Visual Studio. From there, the call stack looks something like this:

```
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) + 0x1f3 bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xad bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x47 bytes    
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0x30a bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext context) + 0xcd bytes  
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(System.Type t, object existing, string name, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride> resolverOverrides) + 0x285 bytes   
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(System.Type t, string name, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride> resolverOverrides) + 0x4e bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(System.Type t, string name, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) + 0x46 bytes 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll!Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container, System.Type t, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride[] overrides) + 0x71 bytes   
Unity.Mvc3.dll!Unity.Mvc3.UnityDependencyResolver.GetService(System.Type serviceType) + 0x9f bytes  
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Type controllerType) + 0x97 bytes 
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Type controllerType) + 0x2b2 bytes    
System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName) + 0x15b bytes  
Kendo.Mvc.dll!Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.ControllerContextCache.ControllerContextFactory(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName, string areaName) + 0x99 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Kendo action was irrelevant to the problem, except for being *just enough* to trigger the Bootstrapper and dependency injection. Since most of the rest of our views are simply inside the Tabstrip, nothing else had a chance to be executed.

Although the error was being thrown to the view, the real problem was a circular reference in our services, for example:

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    private readonly IServiceB _svcB;

    public ServiceA(IServiceB svcB)
    {
        _svcB = svcB
    }
}

public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
    private readonly IServiceA _svcA;

    public ServiceB(IServiceA svcA)
    {
        _svcA = svcA
    }
}
```

Of course, our hierarchy was a little more complex, and hence, the source of the exception was less obvious (especially because the exception was being thrown in the View, rather than in the actual Service).

To solve the problem, I will either inject the base repositories, or move a few common functions into its own service. But since the real struggle was simply determining why the error was occurring, I hope this will save someone some time!